# Tomcat dependency in gradle

Tags: tomcat, gradle

I am trying to use gradle only for the jar dependencies in Eclipse, meaning that I took all the jars from the build path and wrote it like this: compile 'groupid:artifactid:version'.

I am using tomcat 7.0.39 in eclipse (it is imported as a library in the build path of the projects) , and i want to add tomcat to the dependencies, and i wrote this:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
```

and in the dependencies clause:

`providedCompile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:7.0.39'`

And i removed the tomcat library from the build path.

But when i run the server i get this:

```
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:855)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1051)
```

Can someone shed some light on what am i supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `providedCompile` the Jar will not be packaged with the War ie. you are specifying that this dependency is not required at runtime. Try changing `providedCompile` with just `compile` in your Gradle build, this should include the Catalina Jar in your package.